# Jitsi Android SDK crashes (version 6.1.0) after joining call

Tags: java, android, gradle, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am trying to integrate **Jitsi Android SDK** for video Conferences on my app but it crashes as soon as I join/create a meeting. I am using Android Version -

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335, built on September 30, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
```

Here's the java code below for my DashboardActivity.

```
package com.skymeet.videoConference;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeet;
import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity;
import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetConferenceOptions;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText codeBox;
    Button joinBtn, shareBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        codeBox = findViewById(R.id.codeBox);
        joinBtn = findViewById(R.id.joinBtn);
        shareBtn = findViewById(R.id.shareBtn); // not implemented yet

        URL serverURL = null;
        try {
            serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions
                = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                .setServerURL(serverURL)
                .setFeatureFlag("welcomepage.enabled", false)
                .build();

        JitsiMeet.setDefaultConferenceOptions(defaultOptions);




        joinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options
                        = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                        .setRoom(codeBox.getText().toString()).setFeatureFlag("welcomepage.enabled", false)
                        .build();
                JitsiMeetActivity.launch(DashboardActivity.this, options);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have implemented this code with help from https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/dev-guide/dev-guide-android-sdk/

On the Jitsi Android docs they have mentioned this way **but this does not imports Jitsi Android SDK to our project.**

*The repository typically goes into the `build.gradle` file in the root of your project:
build.gradle*

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

*Dependency definitions belong in the individual module `build.gradle` files:*

```
dependencies {
    // (other dependencies)
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:+') { transitive = true }
}
```

Instead, we used to get a warning like this below while syncing the Gradle files.
`Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:6.1.0` ~~
[Check Gradle Warning Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7ihW.jpg)

This can be fixed by placing the repository on `settings.gradle` as below

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

After everything is successfully built & installed on devices, my app crashes as soon as I create or join the meeting. Not able to figure out what is causing my application to crash.

After crashing the error comes this way on my mobile phone.
[Check Error Screenshot on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RGGn.jpg)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.jitsi.meet.sdk

Jits MeetOngoingConferenceService@dc6a12a with Intent(cmp=com.skymeet.videoConference/org.jits i.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService (has extras)}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(chann el-JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel shortcut=null contentView=null vibrate-null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)

at

android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(Activit yThread.java:4802)

at

android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThr

ead.java:276)

at

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Activi

tyThread.java:2156)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:1 06)

at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:210) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java: 8213)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArg sCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.ja

va:1045) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel-JitsiOngoingConfere

nceChannel shortcut-null contentView=null vibrate-null sound-null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa

color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2

vis PUBLIC)

at

android.app.NotificationManager.fixNotification(Noti ficationManager.java:699) at

android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(Notifi cationManager.java:678) at

android.app.NotificationManager.notify(Notification Manager.java:627)

at

android.app.NotificationManager.notify(Notification Manager.java:603) at

org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceServi ce.onStartCommand(JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceS ervice.java:135)

at

android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(Activit yThread.java:4784)

... 9 more
```

Check video for further error references - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXZOtMYQ_Oi1w4UtJ5olyupR13E2HrpV/view?usp=sharing

Can someone please help me with this? I will be grateful enough.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I myself found a solution for this.

1. Right click on res folder in android project and choose image asset
   from new section.
2. Create icon with following config

   **Name: ic_notification**

   **Icon Type: Notification Icons**

Answer (score 0):

Try this implementation for SDK and reference [link](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-sdk-samples/blob/master/android/kotlin/JitsiSDKTest/app/build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
   // Jitsi Meet
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0') { transitive = true }
}
```

Comment: I tried with older versions as well, here we use to get a warning while syncing gradle as shown -
`Failed to resolve: com.github.MatrixFrog:android-scalablevideoview:v1.0.4-jitpack`


And after that while trying to install the app, it gives an error with the build output as - 


`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, i tried to use older version **sdk:5.1.0** and enable Jetfier . It fixed my issue.

1. Go to **Gradle.properties** add this

   repositories {

   ```
    maven {

        url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven repository/raw/master/releases"

    }
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
   ```

   }
2. Add this in **Build.gradle**

dependencies {

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:5.1.0') { transitive = true }
```

}

3. Go to **gradle.properties** add enableJetfier and set value to true

android.enableJetifier=true