# Invalid notification (no valid small icon). Getting this error in Jitsi meet

Tags: java, android

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService@25a9391 with Intent { cmp=com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting/org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3650)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6737)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(NotificationManager.java:320)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:273)
        at org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService.onStartCommand(JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3624)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6737) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
I/Camera: handleMessage: 16
I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-7886-0](this:0x81c05000,id:0,api:4,p:412,c:7886) queueBuffer: slot 3 is dropped, handle=0x8ef069c0
E/JitsiMeetSDK: JitsiMeetUncaughtExceptionHandler FATAL ERROR
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService@25a9391 with Intent { cmp=com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting/org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3650)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6737)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(NotificationManager.java:320)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:273)
        at org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService.onStartCommand(JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3624)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6737) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
    
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService@25a9391 with Intent { cmp=com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting/org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService (has extras) }: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3650)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6737)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid notification (no valid small icon): Notification(channel=JitsiOngoingConferenceChannel pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0xa color=0x00000000 category=call actions=2 vis=PUBLIC)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser(NotificationManager.java:320)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
        at android.app.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:273)
        at org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService.onStartCommand(JitsiMeetOngoingConferenceService.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3624)


//MY MainActivity incase YOU MAY NEED TO SEE IT

    package com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting.activities;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting.R;
import com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting.network.ApiClient;
import com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting.network.ApiService;
import com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting.utilities.Constants;

import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity;
import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetConferenceOptions;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URL;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;


public class IncomingInvitationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String meetingType = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming_invitation);

        ImageView imageMeetingType = findViewById(R.id.imageMeetingType);
        meetingType = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_MEETING_TYPE);


        if(meetingType != null){
            if(meetingType.equals("video")){
                imageMeetingType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_video);
            }else {
                imageMeetingType.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_audio);
            }
        }
        TextView textFirstChat = findViewById(R.id.textFirstChar);
        TextView textUsername = findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
        TextView textEmail = findViewById(R.id.textEmail);

        String firstName = getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_FIRST_NAME);
        if(firstName != null){
            textFirstChat.setText(firstName.substring(0,1));
        }

        textUsername.setText(String.format(
                "%s %S",
                firstName,
                getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_LAST_NAME)
        ));

        textEmail.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.KEY_EMAIL));

        ImageView imageAcceptInvitation = findViewById(R.id.imageAcceptInvitation);
        imageAcceptInvitation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendInvitationResponse(
                        Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_ACCEPTED,
                        getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITER_TOKEN)
                );
            }
        });

        ImageView imageRejectInvitation = findViewById(R.id.imageRejectInvitation);
        imageRejectInvitation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendInvitationResponse(
                        Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_REJECTED,
                        getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITER_TOKEN)
                );
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendInvitationResponse(String type, String receiverToken){
        try {
            JSONArray tokens = new JSONArray();
            tokens.put(receiverToken);

            JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject();

            data.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_TYPE, Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE);
            data.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE, type);

            body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_DATA, data);
            body.put(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_REGISTRATION_IDS, tokens);

            sendRemoteMessage(body.toString(), type);

        }catch (Exception exception){
            Toast.makeText(this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

    }

    private void sendRemoteMessage(String remoteMassageBody, String type){
        ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class).sendRemoteMessage(
                Constants.getRemoteMessageHeaders(), remoteMassageBody
        ).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Response<String> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    if(type.equals(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_ACCEPTED)){
                        //Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, "Invitation Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            URL serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si");
                            JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder builder = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder();
                            builder.setServerURL(serverURL);
                            builder.setFeatureFlag("welcomepage.enabled", false);
                            builder.setRoom(getIntent().getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_MEETING_ROOM));

                            if(meetingType.equals("audio")){
                                builder.setVideoMuted(true);
                            }

                            JitsiMeetActivity.launch(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, builder.build());
                            finish();

                        }catch (Exception exception){
                            Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else{
                        Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, "Invitation Rejected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<String> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(IncomingInvitationActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver invitationResponseReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String type = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE);
            if(type != null){
                if(type.equals(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_CANCELLED)){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Invitation Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(
                invitationResponseReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Constants.REMOTE_MSG_INVITATION_RESPONSE)
        );
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(
                invitationResponseReceiver
        );
    }
}
```

Am building a conference android app using Jitsi meet SDK. In my code I do not necessarily have Notification, but the error says ***Invalid notification (no valid small icon)**. Maybe this notification was implemented in Jitsi. I have seen some solutions on similar problems but non really fits this. Can anyone help me get rid of this error?

Comment: can you share your notification builder code

Comment: Well, I have edited the question above. I've added MainActicity. However as I said, i don't have any notification builder in all my activities. Maybe this was implemented in Jitsi meet. It's just a dependency that you import  and provides all video calling (conference) features once you link to it. You can see my code as put above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74206547/14784590 answered here too.

Answer (score 1):

Create a notification icon with the name "ic_notification".
Steps :

1. Right click drawable folder and click New->Image Asset
2. Select Notification icons from icon type.
3. Note : the name of the icon must be : **ic_notification**

Now try running your project.

[image]